# Import Outlook contacts in website?

Tags: api, outlook, contacts

I am totaly lost here, I want a step by step example of how to import Outlook contacts in a website using PHP and Javascript.

MSDN documentation is not clear, there is no example of how to implement Outlook API in a website.

Edit: I want example of how to implement invite friends using email contacts something like what is implemented in facebook, also how to do sign in with facebook or google ..etc.

Comment: Where does the Outlook data live? Exchange mailbox? PST file? Where will your code run? Server? Client side Java script?

Answer (score 0):

A one time migration of data can be done by exporting contacts from Outlook to Excel or Access.

Go to `File` - `Import & Export` - `Export to a file` - `MS-Excel` and then select the folder with `contacts`.

This file can then be imported in the database of your website.

A continuous connection between a website and your contacts will require the usage of Exchange server in combination with your webserver, where the Live API can be used e.g. in combination with Active Directory.

Answer (score 0):

The [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757/en-us?wa=wsignin1.0) article states the following:

**Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.**

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

I'd suggest using any other mechanisms for extracting contacts from Outlook.

Answer (score 0):

WL.init({
    client_id: APP_CLIENT_ID,
    redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URL,
    scope: ["wl.basic", "wl.contacts_emails"],
    response_type: "token"
});

Import contacts

jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

```
//live.com api
jQuery('#import').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    WL.login({
        scope: ["wl.basic", "wl.contacts_emails"]
    }).then(function (response) 
    {
        WL.api({
            path: "me/contacts",
            method: "GET"
        }).then(
            function (response) {
                    //your response data with contacts 
                console.log(response.data);
            },
            function (responseFailed) {
                //console.log(responseFailed);
            }
        );

    },
    function (responseFailed) 
    {
        //console.log("Error signing in: " + responseFailed.error_description);
    });
});
```

});